# JSON seems to be double encoded by VB Web Service

Tags: vb.net, json, web-services, parsing

Working in VB.NET.  Here's my web service - It's a method on an aspx code behind page, though it behaves the same in an asmx:

```
<WebService(Namespace:="http://mycompany/WebServices/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ScriptService()> _
Partial Class AnAspxPageCodeBehind
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    <WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    Public Shared Function GetSettings(param As String) As String
        Dim something As AClass = DoSomethingWith(param)

        Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(something)
    End Function
```

I call it like this:

```
var dataToSend = '{"param":' + data + '}';

$.ajax({
    url: 'AnAspxCodeBehind.aspx/GetSettings',
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataToSend,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var ret = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data).d);
    }
});
```

Notice the double JSON.parse call in the success function?  When I've done web services before (using C#) I've just had to do var ret = JSON.parse(data.d).

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Thanks

David

Comment: Note the responseformat attribute?  That tells the framework what to do.  It does the serializing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebService framework automactically serializes the result into XML or JSON, depending on the request. You're not supposed to do JSON serialization manually, and if you do, you end up with double-encoded result.

Just return a regular string, or object, or a list of objects from your function. The framework will do the rest. In your case, declare the function `As AClass`.

You also won't need to call `JSON.parse` on the client side. jQuery will parse it for you and pass the parsed object in `data`.

Comment: OK - I'll give that a go.  But why the different behaviour between C# and VB?

Comment: Well, The server side code seems good, but on the client side I still have to do JSON.parse(data).d.
In the past I've done JSON.parse(data.d).

Comment: @DavidHyde Apparently your C# service was set up differently. Maybe it had different attributes applied to classes, or maybe it wasn't a WebService application at all. I just set up a C# WebService app with the attributes from your question, and it works exactly as the VB version.

Comment: @DavidHyde `JSON.parse(data.d)` doesn't make too much sense -- it requires `data` to be already parsed, with `d` containing double-encoded json. In my test setup here `success: function (data) {alert(data.d.foo);}` works fine, with `foo` being a property of the returned `AClass` object.